# How to use a resolver with angular routing

Tags: angular, routes, resolver

I have a resolver service that retrieves data from the db in transition, I receive the data in the service but not in the called component - it's undefine in the onInit

```
export class WorkShopResolverService implements Resolve<WorkShop | null>{

  constructor(private workShopService: WorkShopService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<WorkShop | null>{

    const workShopUuid = route.paramMap.get("workShopUuid");
    console.log("workShopUuid",workShopUuid);
    return this.workShopService.findWorkShopByUuid(Number(workShopUuid?.toString()));

  }
}
```

the component where I want to retrieve the information:

> export class CreateWorkshopComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
> workShop!: WorkShop | null; ...}

app-routing:

> {
> path: 'createWorkShop/:workShopUuid',
> component: CreateWorkshopComponent,
> resolve:{
> workShop: WorkShopResolverService
> }
> },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component you need to access your data from ActivatedRoute data.

```
  ...
  constructor(
    ...
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const workShopData = this.route.snapshot.data.workShop;
  }
```